# HQL left join: Path expected for join

Tags: java, hibernate, hql

I am new at Hibernate, and I have a question regarding HQL Left join.

I try to left join 2 tables, patient and provider, and keep getting "Path expected for join!" error on the second table. Appreciate it if anybody can help on this issue!

Here is the mapping of the 2 tables/classes:

patient.hbm.xmL:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Mapping DTD 3.0//EN" "http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-mapping package="com.ccg.db.test">
    <class name="patient" table="patient">
        <id name="patientId" column="patientId" type="int">
            <generator class="native"/>
        </id>
        <property name="patientName" type="string" >
           <column name="patientName" /> 
        </property>
        <property name="providerId" type="string" >
            <column name="provId" /> 
        </property>
        <many-to-one name="provider" column="providerId" class="provider" /> 
    </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

---

provider.hbm.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Mapping DTD 3.0//EN" "http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-mapping package="com.ccg.db.test">
    <class name="provider" table="provider">
        <id name="providerId" column="providerId">
            <generator class="native" />
        </id>
        <property name="providerName" column="providerName" />
    </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

---

pojo:

```
patient.java

package com.ccg.db.test;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.List;
import org.hibernate.Session;

public class patient 
implements Serializable
{
    private int patientId;
    private String patientName;
    private String providerId; // foreign key to provider

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 81073;

    public static void load(Session session, List<String> values){
        patient PatientInfo = new patient(); 

        PatientInfo.setPatientId(Integer.parseInt(values.get(0)));
        PatientInfo.setPatientName( values.get(1));
        PatientInfo.setProviderId( values.get(2) );

        session.save( PatientInfo );
    }

    /**
    * @return the PatientId
    */
    public int getPatientId() {
        return patientId;
    }

    /**
    * @param PatientId the PatientId to set
    */
    public void setPatientId(int PatientId) {
        this.patientId = PatientId;
    }

    /**
    * @return the PatientName
    */
    public String getPatientName() {
        return this.patientName;
    }

    /**
    * @param PatientName the PatientName to set
    */
    public void setPatientName(String PatientName) {
        this.patientName = PatientName;
    }

    /**
    * @return the ProvId
    */
    public String getProviderId() {
        return this.providerId;
    }

    /**
    * @param id the ProviderId to set
    */
    public void setProviderId( String id ) {
        this.providerId = id;
    }

    /**
    * @return the ProvId
    */
    public String getProvider() {
        return this.providerId;
    }

    /**
    * @param id the ProviderId to set
    */
    public void setProvider( String id ) {
        this.providerId = id;
    }  

    /**
    * @param args
    */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }
}

provider.java:

package com.ccg.db.test;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.List;

import org.hibernate.Session;

public class provider 
implements Serializable
{
    private String providerId;
    private String providerName;

    //private int patientId;
    //private int providerSpec; 

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 81073;

    public static void load(Session session, List<String> values){
        provider ProviderInfo = new provider(); 

        ProviderInfo.setProviderId( values.get(0) );
        ProviderInfo.setProviderName( values.get(1));
        //ProviderInfo.setProviderSpec( Integer.parseInt(values.get(2)) );

        session.save( ProviderInfo );
    }

    /**
    * @return the ProviderName
    */
    public String getProviderName() {
        return providerName;
    }

    /**
    * @param ProviderName the ProviderName to set
    */
    public void setProviderName(String name) {
        this.providerName = name;
    }

    /**
    * @return the ProvId
    */
    public String getProviderId() {
        return this.providerId;
    }

    /**
    * @param id the ProvId to set
    */
    public void setProviderId( String id ) {
        this.providerId = id;
    }

    /*
    public int getPatientId() {
        return this.patientId;
    }

    public void setPatientId( int id ) {
        this.patientId = id;
    }
    */

    /**
    * @param args
    */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }
}
```

---

Here is the left join query:

```
select
    pat.patientId, pat.patientName
from
    patient as pat 
left join
    provider as pro 
where
    pat.providerId = pro.providerId
```

---

and here is the result:

```
0:50:08,479 INFO query:156 - Query = outerJoin
10:50:08,479 INFO query:157 - select
pat.patientId, pat.patientName
from
patient as pat 
left join
provider as pro 
where
pat.providerId = pro.providerId

10:50:08,698 ERROR PARSER:33 - Path expected for join!
10:50:08,698 ERROR PARSER:33 - Invalid path: 'pro.providerId'
10:50:08,698 ERROR PARSER:33 - right-hand operand of a binary operator was null
10:50:08,698 ERROR query:184 - Problem generating query.
org.hibernate.hql.ast.QuerySyntaxException: Path expected for join! [select
pat.patientId, pat.patientName
from
com.ccg.db.test.patient as pat 
left join
provider as pro 
where
pat.providerId = pro.providerId
]
at org.hibernate.hql.ast.QuerySyntaxException.convert(QuerySyntaxException.java:31)
at org.hibernate.hql.ast.QuerySyntaxException.convert(QuerySyntaxException.java:24)
at org.hibernate.hql.ast.ErrorCounter.throwQueryException(ErrorCounter.java:59)
at org.hibernate.hql.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.analyze(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:235)
at org.hibernate.hql.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.doCompile(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:160)
at org.hibernate.hql.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.compile(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:111)
at org.hibernate.engine.query.HQLQueryPlan.(HQLQueryPlan.java:77)
at org.hibernate.engine.query.HQLQueryPlan.(HQLQueryPlan.java:56)
at org.hibernate.engine.query.QueryPlanCache.getHQLQueryPlan(QueryPlanCache.java:72)
at org.hibernate.impl.AbstractSessionImpl.getHQLQueryPlan(AbstractSessionImpl.java:133)
at org.hibernate.impl.AbstractSessionImpl.createQuery(AbstractSessionImpl.java:112)
at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.createQuery(SessionImpl.java:1623)
at com.ccg.db.query.QueryManager.query(QueryManager.java:163)
at com.ccg.db.query.QueryManager.query(QueryManager.java:139)
at com.ccg.db.query.QueryManager.main(QueryManager.java:80)
```

Comment: If you want help, you need to show more respect for the time of those helping you and format your code to something readable.  I'll give you one for free - the question should be almost readable now.

Answer (score 26):

Your patient has a reference to the provider, and also has the provider id as a property.  I would probably get rid of the provider id property on the patient and just have the reference to the provider.  Then your query should be something like this.

```sql
select pat.patientId, pat.patientName 
from patient as pat 
left join pat.provider as pro
```

To join, you need the association path from your patient to your provider, which in this case is pat.provider.  Then hibernate will automatically use the "column" specified in the many-to-one mapping to join into the provider table.  In your case, the join doesn't make a lot of sense since you aren't querying on any properties of the provider, so something like this might make more sense

```sql
select pat 
from patient as pat 
join pat.provider as pro 
where pat.patientName = 'John' 
and pro.name = 'United Healthcare'
```

There you are able to filter your patient list to patients named John that have United Healthcare as the provider.