# Hibernate JOIN error syntax exception

Tags: mysql, sql, hibernate, select, join

In my project (java struts 2, hibernate), I want to select with join between 2 table.

```
Class User {
  private int userId;
  private String userName;
  private String dateOfBirth;
}

Class Bill {
  private int billId;
  private String dateOfBill;
  private Double moneyOfBill;
  private User user;
}
```

It is OK when I tried via sql in localhost DB directly

```
Select * From user u JOIN bill b ON (b.userId=u.userId) Group by b.userId Order by Sum(b.moneyOfBill) asc;
```

But it is error in my program via hibernate hql

```
From User U JOIN Bill B ON (B.user.userId=U.userId) Group by B.user.userId Order by Sum(B.moneyOfBill) ASC;
```

The error in eclipse console:

> at org.hibernate.hql.ast.QuerySyntaxException.convert(QuerySyntaxException.java:54)
>       at org.hibernate.hql.ast.QuerySyntaxException.convert(QuerySyntaxException.java:47)
>       at org.hibernate.hql.ast.ErrorCounter.throwQueryException(ErrorCounter.java:82)
>       at org.hibernate.hql.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.parse(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:281)
>       at org.hibernate.hql.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.doCompile(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:180)
>       at org.hibernate.hql.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.compile(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:134)
>       at org.hibernate.engine.query.HQLQueryPlan.(HQLQueryPlan.java:101)
>       at org.hibernate.engine.query.HQLQueryPlan.(HQLQueryPlan.java:80)
>       at org.hibernate.engine.query.QueryPlanCache.getHQLQueryPlan(QueryPlanCache.java:94)
>       at org.hibernate.impl.AbstractSessionImpl.getHQLQueryPlan(AbstractSessionImpl.java:156)
>       at org.hibernate.impl.AbstractSessionImpl.createQuery(AbstractSessionImpl.java:135)
>       at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.createQuery(SessionImpl.java:1650)

Please help. Thank you!

Comment: This solution fixes my problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16354705/hql-join-path-expected-for-join-hibernate

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT U.userId, U.userName, U.dateOfBirth
FROM Bill B 
JOIN USER U 
GROUP BY U.userId, U.userName, U.dateOfBirth 
ORDER BY SUM(B.moneyOfBill) ASC;
```

Comment: Thanks Saharsh Shah, but I just want to get user data from User table, not bill data.

Comment: I found the solution is here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16354705/hql-join-path-expected-for-join-hibernate.